# Edit and search an URL with JS

Tags: javascript, search, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make an easy google chrome extension that gets a string from a textbox and adds it to an URL (ie "https://www.google.com/search?q=") and then google the URL+ input string.
How should i make it?

i must say that i'm a beginner, i was thinking of a function that reads the input from the textbox and adds it to the URL. something like this: var google = "google.com/search?q=" + textbox

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus.html (via right-click), or https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html (on the fly)

Comment: I think you need to be a bit more specific than "How should I make it". You'll get a better response if you discuss the ideas you have had so far, so others can elaborate and add to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this maybe ?

Getting the content of the textbox (assuming the target input has a textbox id ofc):

> var query = document.getElementById('textbox').value

Redirection:

> window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=' + query

I'm not quite sure of what you'd exactly like though.

Comment: i've almost solved it `function Check(form)
    {
 var name = document.searcher.name.value;
 var url="http://www.google.com/search?q=" + name;
window.open(url);
 }`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the omnibox api in order to get what you need. I've wrote a detailed explanation on this solution here: http://greenido.wordpress.com/2013/03/28/chrome-extension-for-enterprise-internal-usage/

Btw, I hope you gave google.com search just as an example... because it's the default behavior :)

Comment: "that gets a string from **a textbox** and adds it to an URL". The OP was probably not referring to the omnibox.